# Why is UITableViewCell taking long gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIView`, lets call it view_A. There's a `UIViewController`, call it mainViewController. Inside it there is a `UIButton`. On tapping that button I add the view_A as a subview to mainViewController's view. The tableview has several menu items in it. The problem is the tableview is not responding to the touch correctly. I have to tap the cell long to make a selection. There's no gesture added on it. There's no other view covering it. It's absolutely bizzare, this behavior. Please take a look at the following code and point out what might be causing the trouble.
This is the delegate implementation/presentations in mainViewcontroller:

```
 -(void) showDropDownMenu: (UIButton *) sender
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DropDownMenuView" bundle:nil];
        self.myView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        self.myView.hidden = NO;
        self.myView.tag = 101;
        self.myView.delegate = self;
        self.myView.btnBack.hidden = YES;
        CATransition *transition = nil;
        transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.2;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromBottom ;
        transition.delegate = self;
        [self.myView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:self.myView];

    }

-(void) hideDropDownMenu
{
   CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.2;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [self.myView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    self.myView.tag = 102;
    [UIView commitAnimations];



}
-(void) navigateBack
{

}
-(void) themeSelected: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.item);
    themeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(indexPath.row+1)];
    [self setUpTheme];
}
```

This is implementation of the cell.h file:

```
@interface ThemeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *themeName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *themePreview;
```

This is implementation of cell.m file:

```
#import "ThemeTableViewCell.h"
@implementation ThemeTableViewCell
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    //ORIGINAL 82
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

1. My View_A .h file can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10387746/).
2. View_A.m file can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10387765/).

UPDATE: I logged the gestures and turns out somehow long press gesture is set to cells.

Comment: your tablecell contain any accessory view(like check box, detail disclosure button etc) in which OS this problem occurs.  In one of my project i face same problem in IOS7.0 i use accessory view in UItableviewcell.  To solve this issue I remove this view.

Comment: No it is a plain tableview. The cells have only imageview in them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you disable cell imageview userInteraction, if no try this `cell.yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`

Comment: I don't think it'd have any effect on cell's performance but anyhow i tried that and the problem still persists.

Comment: try this to check your cell have gesture or not `for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in cell.contentView.gestureRecognizers) {
        NSLog(@"%i  gesture type %@",indexPath.row, gesture.class);
//        NSLog(@"min %f",((UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture).minimumPressDuration);
        NSLog(@"isEnabled %d",gesture.enabled);
    }`

Comment: Blimey. It says Long gestures. But I didn't add any gestures at all as you can see in the code. What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: it's normal long gesture is a default gesture but I don't know what kind of problem could be, you can update your question and tell as more about ThemeTableViewCell and I will try to help you.

Comment: I tried adding tap gesture to cell and it works. But I'd like to know what caused addition of long tap gesture to the cell. I will update the question.

Comment: I read apple documentation about UITableViewCell, there is no reference about cell gestures.I was also interested why long gesture :))

Comment: any luck after seeing the cell?